# Getting number of rows while foreach is running

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm sending mails using foreach loop for getting recipient info in a codeigniter method of a controller , and, if a mail gets sent, I update recipient status in recipients table to 'sent'.

In another method of the same controller (using the same model), I get number of unsent mails, but if I try to get the number of unsent mails while they are being sent, it waits until foreach loop gets done.

How can I continuously get number of unsent mails, while they are being sent in the foreach loop?

```
recipients table
    id int 11
    recipient_id int 11
    mail_id int 11
    sent tinyint 1
    failed tinyint 1

$recipients = $this->MMails->GetRecipients($mail_id);
foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    //send message using swift
    if($message_sent) {
        $this->MMails->MarkAsSent($recipient_id);//this recipient table gets updated actually, but I can't read the new COUNT value until this loop finished
    }
}
```

from the model:

```
 function GetNumOfQueued() {//Get number of queued mails
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as num_of_queued
        FROM recipients 
        WHERE sent = 0");
    return $query->row()->num_of_queued;
}//GetNumOfQueued

 function MarkAsSent($recipient_id) {//Update mail recipient status to sent
    $this->db->set('sent', 1);
    $this->db->where('id', $recipient_id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->update('recipients');

}//MarkAsSent
```

Simply put, PHP doesn't respond until the loop gets finished, and I can't open any other page in the application while the loop is active.

Settings in my local php.ini is output_buffering = Off

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping the count of unsent mail in the database and get it using a query.

Comment: That's what I'm trying, but I can't get the number while the loop is active, neither by using jquery or php

Answer (score 0):

PHP class instances are created per request, so if you want to be able to get information while it is still running you will need to either write the data to a table in MySQL or using something like `Memcached` or `APC`.

Comment: I am writing the data into recipients table. But can't get the COUNT value while the loop is sending mails. When the loop gets finished, I get the value.

Comment: Is each write to the table atomic? Can you post your foreach loop?

Comment: no, I'm not. It's not only the problem when I try to get the COUNT from db, but even when I try to get a random number as a return from GetNumQueued function. Simply, php doesn't respond while the foreach loop is active

Comment: Ahh, this sounds like something else entirely then - you probably need to look at your Apache/PHP config to see how many concurrent requests you can handle.

Comment: It's possible. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a counter?

```
$recipients = $this->MMails->GetRecipients($mail_id);
$messages_to_send = count($recipients);
foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    //send message using swift
    if($message_sent){
        $messages_to_send--; 
        $this->MMails->MarkAsSent($recipient_id);
    }
}
```

---

Output buffering should do the trick:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

It will allow other execution while the loop runs.

Here is an example of ob outputting on the screen while a loop is processed:

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){

        echo "<br> Line to show.$i";
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
}

echo "Done.";
ob_end_flush();
```

-http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#54841

---

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

$recipients = $this->MMails->GetRecipients($mail_id);
$messages_to_send = count($recipients);
foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    //send message using swift
    if($message_sent){
        $messages_to_send--; 
        $this->MMails->MarkAsSent($recipient_id);
        echo "<br> Emails left to send: .$messages_to_send";
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
echo "All emails have been sent.";
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Yes, I can, but I either can't get the number of queued while the loop is active. PHP doesn't respond to new requests. I've update the question details now.

Comment: So are you trying to display a counter? Is that the end goal?

Comment: `$messages_to_send` will only be available to `$this` instance.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to display the number of queued messages using js timer and jquery. The other problem is that I can't use the whole script while it sends mails...

Comment: @doublesharp: I see your point, but I'm afraid I'll not be able to get the value via ajax. I even can't get ANY value while the loop is active (including some random values)

Comment: @mpet I think you might need to look at output buffering: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: @stormdrain it might be the problem, as it works online, but doesn't work on my localhost. I also can't flush output, I get php output when a script (other ones) gets done only.

Comment: @stormdrain: Settings in my local php.ini is output_buffering = Off

Comment: @stormdrain: it updates output buffer, but doesn't enable parallel execution of a php script (can't get number of queued mails until the loop ends)

Comment: @mpet if you combine the counter with ob, it should do the trick. I updated the answer.